# Is decode-interrupt supported in libjpeg?

Tags: c++, jpeg, libjpeg

I am using libjpeg for decode jpeg file.
when decoding a large image, user may switch to another jpeg file, So is  decode-interrupt supported by libjpeg?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Libjpeg has an [I/O suspension feature](http://www.jpegcameras.com/libjpeg/libjpeg-3.html#ss3.6). So yes you can suspend an encoding/decoding process (and resume it later), or simply interrupt it (with no wish to continue later).

You can provide a customized input routines to libjpeg (by setting up a `jpeg_source_mgr` structure), and then use the [I/O Suspension](http://www.jpegcameras.com/libjpeg/libjpeg-3.html#ss3.6) provided by libjpeg.

Quoting from the libjpeg doc, suspension is very simple :

> For decompression suspension, use a fill_input_buffer() routine that simply returns FALSE (except perhaps during error recovery, as discussed below). This will cause the decompressor to return to its caller with an indication that suspension has occurred.

The suspension can occur at early stages (like when calling `jpeg_read_header`). Also from the doc :

> This can happen at four places :

```
jpeg_read_header(): will return JPEG_SUSPENDED.
jpeg_start_decompress(): will return FALSE, rather than its usual TRUE.
jpeg_read_scanlines(): will return the number of scanlines already completed (possibly 0).
jpeg_finish_decompress(): will return FALSE, rather than its usual TRUE.
```

Suspension implements some backtracking, in order to offer a way to "resume" the encoding/decoding process. It can be expensive (I have no clue about it), so you may test it to see if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure i understand your problem.

As far as i recall you do the usual boiler-plate up to `jpeg_start_decompress()`, then you start reading the lines via `jpeg_read_scanlines()` iteratively. If you need to cancel the operation, break out of the loop reading the scanlines.
If you need better responsiveness, read in smaller chunks.

Comment: Many thanks!
So you mean, if I want to interrupt decoding, I need to modify libjpeg source code, right?

Comment: decoding an image needs 1000ms, at 300ms I decide to cancel decoding.
I wish the decoder can interrupt immediately

Comment: While decoding an image might need 1000ms, one call to jpeg_read_scanlines() should be fast if you read small chunks.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your question really:

```
"is libjpg thread safe?"
```

I think it basically would be, if the underlying stdio library is or you are not using jpeg_stdio_src. However, to be on "the bright side of life", I'd follow Georg's advice of checking after every read_scanline for a pending interrupt (your interrupt handler could set an interrupt-pending flag). That is how I solved that issue (where I needed preemptive scheduling of threads).

Comment: Are you sure? because http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=8702 says it isn't